# Multiple Configs under single instance of flyway

Tags: flyway

Can we maintain different configs under single installation of flyway ? Means if i want to install flyway on central server and perform deployment for multiple services ?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to maintain different configurations for e.g. dev/test/prod of the same application or different applications under the same installation.

> install flyway on central server and perform deployment for multiple services

This is the defacto approach for continuous delivery pipelines.

Achieve this by having application/ environment specific configuration files and use the `-configFiles` option.

Refer the doc: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/#config-files